# Apache ServerName not in any virtual host but still get's redirected to https

Tags: apache-2.4

I've got three virtualhosts enabled

- 000-default.conf (*:80)  => supposed to be default for everything not in any other vhost
- domain.conf (*:80 redirects to https) => ServerAlias domain.local
- domain-le-ssl.conf (*:443)(made by certbot) => ServerAlias domain.local

My situation is that I can access my web server with the IP address and get to the root in 000-default.conf but if I try any other domain like example1.local, it goes to https and throws an SSL certificate error and thus I conclude it uses the domain.conf virtual host.

How can I make sure 000-default.conf also catches ServerNames not in other virtual hosts?

What I've tried:
In 000-default.conf

```
VirtualHost _default_:80>

ServerAlias *
```

My three virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerAlias *
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dir1
    <Directory /var/www/dir1>
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "Please login."
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/apache.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.be
    ServerAlias example.be
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.be
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.be
    ServerAlias www.example.be
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.be/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.be/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.be/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the SSL VirtualHost to be used on one domain, set the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` directives accordingly. Anything that doesn't match will then fall through to the default VirtualHost. For clarity, you may also want to numerically identify the order of your configuration files.

**Note:** if *any* traffic arrives on the port configured in the SSL VirtualHost, it will always be served as HTTPS, and will display certificate errors if the hostname does not match the certificate.

---

For example:

**000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myserver.example.local
  ServerAlias example.local
  DocumentRoot /var/www/default

  ...

</VirtualHost>
```

**001-domain.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  Redirect permanent / https://www.domain.com/

  ...

</VirtualHost>
```

**002-domain-ssl.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com

  ...

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I've done that though, I set a ServerName and ServerAlias in the other vhosts.
The ServerAlias * is only in the 000-default.config.
Could it be something certbot does behind the scenes?

Comment: You should not need to use `ServerAlias *` - if the request doesn't match any higher-order VirtualHosts, it will fall through to the default.

Comment: I added my virtual host files, see anything that's wrong?

Comment: The HSTS was client related as it turns out, nothing wrong with the config, the best answer led me to this conclusion and made me adapt a best practice to the host files names. All my files are now 00*-domain.conf

Comment: @zerobytes I don't get how the accepted answer solved the problem. Renaming the .conf files shouldn't have made any difference. Why isn't `000-default.conf` being the default?

Comment: @Gustavo Apache will load files in alpha-numeric order, hence 000 will be loaded before 001 and 002. Most of the time `.conf` files in `sites-enabled` or `conf.d` will be loaded via an `Include` within `https.conf`.

Comment: @CraigWatson In the original setting `000-default.conf` was already the "default". No need for renaming. Still, Apache was not selecting it when had no matches.